# Paypal click button is not working on safari

Tags: javascript, angular

I am troublinig with the paypal button click is not working specially in safari browser, and rest all browsers its working fine for me,

The issues is i am getting while i am clicking paypal button:
**An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.**

ERROR:

> ppxo_button_pre_template_click

```
Object{
country: "US"
env: "production"
host: "localhost:4200"
lang: "en"
pageID: "27fc589f4a"
path: "/"
referer: "localhost:4200"
timestamp: 1507207991057
uid: "0b1089af2f"
ver: "4.0.131"
windowID: "5cf026dfb9"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue since you are working locally. Try to do the following:
In your address bar type: **https://localhost:4200** I added and "s" to the http://. This will be a quick hack. When you deploy this to your actual domain, some of this errors go away if not you can purchase an SSL certificate for your website. Also you might want to take a look to Paypal's documentation on security

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/info-security-guidelines/

Comment: when i put "https:    //xxxxx", then it is not showing nothing, because of we not created https server on browser